# Discrepancy between when data returns and when it gets rendered in a REACT page

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm having an issue with this code...

```
function Home() {
  
  const[loadingData, setLoadingData] =  useState(true)
 // const columns = useMemo(()=> Columns)
  const[data, setData] = useState([])

 

  useEffect(() => {
    async function getData() {
      await axios
      .get("http://localhost:5000/tests")
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data[0].id);
        console.log(loadingData)
        setData(res.data);
        setLoadingData(false);
      });
        
    }
      if (loadingData) {
        getData();
      } 
   },[]);
 
  const rowData = [
  {
    id: '123-456-AB2',
    accessorName1: data[2].name,
    accessorName2: 'another value0',
    accessorName3: 'tim'
  }]
  
  
    return (
     
      // this.state.items && <h1>{this.state.items.map((item) => JSON.stringify(item.id))}</h1>
      <>
      <h1>{console.log(data)}</h1> 
      {/* <h1>{console.log(rowData[0].accessorName1)}</h1>  */}
      <SideBar collapsed={false}>
      <NavHeader label="Nemo" message="Welcome!" avatarImage='../images/nemo.jpg' />
        <SideBarNavItemContainer>
          <SideBarNavItem to="/bar" icon={<Clipboard />} label="Home" />
          <SideBarNavItem
            to="/something"
            icon={<Blip />}
            label="New Test"
          />
          <SideBarNavItem to="/foo" icon={<Grid />} label="Collections" />
          <SideBarNavItem to="/foo" icon={<Report />} label="Reporting" />
        </SideBarNavItemContainer>
        </SideBar>
        
        {loadingData ? (<p>Loading, please wait...</p>) :
        (<Table rowData={rowData} columns={Columns} />)}
        
        
      </>

 

    );
  }
```

My issue is that that `const rowData` isn't getting populated soon enough to get rendered by the Table component and I'm not sure what I need to do to sort out this timing issue. How can I ensure that that API call is complete before forming the const? Can do something to check if 'data' has a value before setting it into rowData?

Thank you

Comment: When using async/await there is no point to using ```.then``` so you can use it like: ```let response = await axios.get(....``` not sure if this fixes the problem though.